# Why it is shown HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have worked on demo login application on spring. This is my LoginController.java:

```
       package com.pran.pal.controller;


    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;   
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 

   @Controller

public class LoginController extends HttpServlet{

     @RequestMapping(value="/login" ,method=RequestMethod.GET) 
     public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 

         String userName=request.getParameter("userName"); 
         String password=request.getParameter("password"); 
         String message; 
         if(userName != null && !userName.equals("") && userName.equals("admin") 
         && password != null && !password.equals("") && password.equals("123")){ 
             message = "Welcome " +userName + "."; 
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message);   
        }
         else{ 
             message = "Wrong username or password."; 
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message); 
        } 
    }
```

I have used eclipse Neon, Tomcat v9.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pran.pal</groupId>
  <artifactId>LoginSystemPAL</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>LoginSystemPAL Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>LoginSystemPAL</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet> 
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>com.pran.pal.controller.LoginController</servlet-class> 
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>   
  <servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>   

</web-app>
```

> It has shown that input username and password that:
>
> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>
> type Status report
>
> message HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>
> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested
>   resource.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well your class *isn't* `com.pran.pal.controller` - it's `com.pran.pal.controller.LoginController`. Why have you only specified the package name?

Comment: I have tried both.but both is shown same error

Comment: Well they won't show the *same* error - and you should absolutely have the class name there. Given that that's broken, I suggest you try it again using the correct name, and edit your question accordingly afterwards.

Comment: Your whole setup is flawed. Your `LoginController` isn't a servlet so adding it as a servlet in your `web.xml` isn't going to work. I suggest a basic Spring MVC tutorial to get started.

Answer (score 4):

Your `<servlet-class>` should be `com.pran.pal.controller.LoginController`, but you should also have a dependency to Spring Web from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.4.RELEASE).

Also, you are not using properly the Spring `@Controller` annotation. Please follow a step by step tutorial like the one [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Comment: It is interesting that you did not have compile errors and no dependency to Spring Web. Did you had the Jar in your classpath?

Comment: Nope - it looks like the `LoginController` is not a servlet. I guess it should be some Servlet from the framework instead.